# Несколько картинок каскадом

Tags: jquery, изображения

Хочу сделать несколько картинок каскадом, слева направо как ссылки. Каждая картинка накладывается друг на друга примерно на половину. примерно вот так:

```
<style type="text/css">
.k1 {position: absolute;
width: 286px;
height: 279px;
background: transparent url('1.jpg') center center no-repeat;}
.k2 {position: absolute;
width: 286px;
height: 279px;
background: transparent url('2.jpg') center center no-repeat;
left:15%;}
.k3 {position: absolute;
width: 286px;
height: 279px;
background: transparent url('3.jpg') center center no-repeat;
left:30%;}
</style>
<div class="k1"></div>
<div class="k2"></div>
<div class="k3"></div>
```

и т.д.

Но тут возникает вопрос, как их "оживить" при наведении?

Comment: z-index пробовали менять? http://jsfiddle.net/NsgXn/

Answer (score 4):

> `<div class="k1" onmouseenter="k_a:start(this);" onmouseover="k_a:end(this);"></div>`

Убейте меня ... конечно выигрыш в нагрузке, но на таких мелочах лучше так:

```
<div class="elem"></div>

$('.elem').on({
        'mouseenter': function () {
            $(this).animate({/* */});
        },
        'mouseleave': function () {
            $(this).animate({/* */});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавь всем один ещё один класс или id или навесь событие. Я люблю навешивать инлайново =)

```
<div class="k1" onmouseenter="k_a:start(this);" onmouseover="k_a:end(this);"></div>
<div class="k2" onmouseenter="k_a:start(this);" onmouseover="k_a:end(this);"></div>
<div class="k3" onmouseenter="k_a:start(this);" onmouseover="k_a:end(this);"></div>
```

Затем пиши функцию в js

Самая простая анимация при наведении приподнимем вверх, потом опустим.

```
var k_a = {
    start:function(elem){
        elem.animate({ marginTop: "-10px", z-index: 1000; }, 200);
    },
    end:function(elem){
        elem.animate({ marginTop: 0, z-index: 0}, 200);
   }
}
```

Смотри больше в гугле =)

[.animate() JQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Спасибо большое, а возможно ли это дело организовать на css и html?

Comment: Если только на html и css, посмотрите в сторону css transition. Примеры можно тут посмотреть:

http://shpargalkablog.ru/2011/07/transformaciya-css.html